# FIleNotFoundException Java - can't find txt-file

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to read a *.txt* file to the eclipse Console, but i cant seem to figure out what the problem is, im always getting a `FileNotFoundException` when i want to read it in - here's my code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    BufferedReader in;
    in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./morse-code.txt"));
    String line = "";
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null ){
        String parts[] = line.split("\t");
        map.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
    }
    in.close();
    System.out.println(map.toString());
}
```

The file is in the right directory, i checked if the IDE is searching in the right path with:

```
String curDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
System.out.println("Current sys dir: " + curDir);
```

But still, if i want to read from the file i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\User\workspace\AuD\morse-code.txt (Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at orkgrunzer.OrkGrunzer.main(OrkGrunzer.java:16)
```

I cant find the problem, maybe somebody can help me with this :)

Comment: Do have any package defined?

Comment: If you execute `notepad C:\Users\User\workspace\AuD\morse-code.txt` in the Command Prompt, does that file open?

Comment: You read the user directory here:`System.getProperty("user.dir");` not the current working directory

Comment: Try using the absolute path instead of relative.

Answer (score 0):

To shield yourself from the file system you may put your file on the root of the *classpath* and load it this way:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(Class.class.getResourceAsStream("/morse-code.txt")));
```

If you decide to put it below some folders like:

```
resources/files/codes/morse-code.txt
```

and put the folder `resources` on the *classpath* then you have to reference it by:

```
"/files/codes/morse-code.txt"
```